# text keeps pushing image down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div class which is editable, and i have an image on the top right corner of the div. However when i input text and the text proceeds to the next line the image moves from the top right to underneath the text. Is there a way to fix it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="note" contenteditable="true"> <span id='close' contenteditable='false' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>
    <img src="images/close.png" height="25" width="25" align="right" style="vertical-align: top; float: right"/>
</span></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $(".note").resizable();
    $(".note").keyup(function(){
        $(this).css('height' , '100%');
    });
    $(".note").draggable()
    .click(function() {
        $(this).draggable( {disabled: false});
    })
    .dblclick(function() {
        $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
    });                                      
});
```

**CSS**

```
.note {
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Note;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-image: url("images/stickynote.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGePeb   **EDIT:** Question was already solved, didn't notice. Still have the pen :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
position:relative;
```

to .note and then add

```
.note img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```